# Get Data fro a DataSet Based on the Caption property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm consuming a WCF service to get data for another database.
There is a webmethod GetAnalyst which retuns a dataSet.

```
 public  DataSet GetAnalysts()
  {
  }
```

The list of analysts is present in the first table:

```
List<Analyst> Analysts = new List<Analyst>();
            DataSet ds = null;
            try
            {
                ds = EServiceClient.GetAnalysts();
            }

if (ds != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        var analyst = new Analyst()
                        {
                            Name = row[1].ToString(),
                            LastName = row[2].ToString(),
                            PhoneNumber = row[3].ToString(),
                            Email = row[4].ToString()
                        };
                        sectorService.SetSectorByName(ref analyst, row[0].ToString());
                        Analysts.Add(analyst);
                    }
                }
```

The problem is that the index changes, sometimes the name is the first, sometimes is in the  column 2 nd ....

The only thing which is fix is the caption of columns. for example the caption of the column which contains the name is Name ....

How can i retrieve the properties basing on the Caption.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just wrote a method to get the index based on the caption value

```
public virtual int GetIndexByCaption(string caption, DataTable dt)
        {
            int columnIndex = -1;
            try
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.Caption == caption)
                    {
                        columnIndex = dt.Columns.IndexOf(column);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return columnIndex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `row["columnname"].ToString()` to retrieve the data based on the actual column name and not the column index.

Comment: i'have not the columname, i have just the caption witch is fix

Comment: You can only get the data by column name or index